# Copy files from one user home directory to another user home directory in Linux

Tags: linux, security, shell, copy, sudo

I have the logins and passwords for two linux users (not root), for example user1 and user2.

How to copy files 
from **/home/user1/folder1** to **/home/user2/folder2**, using one single shell script (one single script launching, without manually switching of users).

I think I must use a sudo command but didn't found how exactly.

Answer (score 6):

Just this:

```
cp -r /home/user1/folder1/ /home/user2/folder2
```

If you add `-p` (so `cp -pr`) it will preserve the attributes of the files (mode, ownership, timestamps).

`-r` is required to copy hidden files as well. See [How to copy with cp to include hidden files and hidden directories and their contents?](https://superuser.com/questions/61611/how-to-copy-with-cp-to-include-hidden-files-and-hidden-directories-and-their-con) for further reference.

Comment: Uhms you are right @Alfe , just updated handling it. `-r` makes it.

Comment: Doesn't get any better.  Now you will create a `/home/user2/folder2/folder1/…`

Comment: The only other option is to use `cp /home/user1/folder1 /home/user2/` and then rename that `/home/user2/folder1` to `/home/user2/folder2` (only works if both didn't exist before).

Comment: this task copy file from one user to another user require any admin permission? @Alfe and fedorqui

Comment: No, not in general.  To perform the copy you have to have permissions to read the original from its location and to have permissions to write it into its destination.  By this you will create a new file which is owned by the user which is doing this (no matter which the destination you choose).  You would need to have admin permissions to change the ownership of the new file, for instance.  But I propose to ask your own question where you can describe all the details of your use case.

Answer (score 4):

sudo cp -a /home/user1/folder1 /home/user2/folder2
sudo chown -R user2:user2 /home/user2/folder2

cp -a archive
chown -R act recursively

Copies the files and then gives permissions to user2 to be able to access them.
Copies all files including dot files, all sub-directories and does not require directory /home/user2/folder2 to exist prior to the command.

Answer (score 1):

```
(shopt -s dotglob; cp -a /home/user1/folder1/* /home/user2/folder2/)
```

Will copy all files (including those starting with a dot) using the standard `cp`.  The `/folder2/` should exist, otherwise the results can be nasty.

Often using a packing tool like `tar` can be of help as well:

```
cd /home/user1/folder1
tar cf - . | (cd /home/user2/folder2; tar xf -)
```

Comment: The above mentioned nastiness is restricted, though.  If the directory does not exist, then you will get a simple error message.  If you happen to forget the `/` in the end _and_ the directory does not exist _and_ the `*` evaluates to exactly one file, than this gets copied into a file which has the name of the spot where the target directory should be located, e.g. `cp /u1/f1/* /u2/f2` with only `/u1/f1/x` being present will result in a file (!) named `/u2/f2` containing the bytes from `/u1/f1/x`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this command

```
sudo -u username /path1/file1 /path2/file2
```

This command allows you to copy the contents as a particular user from any file path.

PS: The parent directory should be list-able at least in order to copy files from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [fedorqui 'SO stop harming'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18869087/10907864) answer.

I had this same challenge when I tried to change the default admin user for a server from `stage_user` to `prod_user` on an **Ubuntu 20.04** machine:

First, I created a `prod_user` using the command below:

```
sudo adduser prod_user
```

And then I added the newly created `prod_user` to the sudo group:

```
sudo adduser prod_user sudo
```

Next, I copied all the directories that I needed from the `home` directory of the `stage_user` to the `prod_user`:

```
sudo cp -r /home/stage_user/folder1/ /home/prod_user/
```

Next, I changed the ownership of the copied folders from `stage_user` to `prod_user` to avoid permission issues:

```
sudo chown prod_user:prod_user /home/prod_user/folder1
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

First, if are in user terminal go to root using

> sudo -i

Find your files then use

> cp filename /home/user

If the file is in some other directory

> cp dir/filename /home/user
> **user> make sure you replace with your username**

To check file move back to user using

> su user

Answer (score -4):

The question has to to do with permissions across users.

I believe by default home permission does allow all people to do listing and changing working directory into another's home:
eg. drwxr-xr-x
Hence in the previous answers people did not realise what you might have encountered.

With more restricted settings like what I had on my web host, nonowner users cannot do anything
eg. drwx------
Even if you use su/sudo and become the other user, you can still only be ONE USER at one time, so when you copy the file back, the same problem of no enough permission still apply.

So. . . use scp instead, treat the whole thing like a network environment let me put it that way and that's it.  By the way this question had already been answered once over here (https://superuser.com/questions/353565/how-do-i-copy-a-file-folder-from-another-users-home-directory-in-linux), only cared to reply because this ranked 1st result from my search.